# deploy Django2 on heroku , but can not open the webpage in browsers

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I did a django project on python, and push it to heroku, but when I try to access it with

```
https://desolate-oasis-71960.herokuapp.com
```

browser can not load it.

I use django2.1.3 on python3, here is my settings.py:

```
import os
import django_heroku 

# Build paths inside the project like this:os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
--snip-

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())

#setting Heroku
cwd = os.getcwd()
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES= {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
}

    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO','https')

    #ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
```

but after I push the project to heroku ,I can not open the webpage, then I run the command:  heroku logs, here is the log :

```
 2018-11-16T03:47:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build      succeeded
 2018-11-16T03:48:48.803513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14      

 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" 
 host=desolate-oasis-71960.herokuapp.com 
 request_id=703f8297-76f6-4434-9fcc-805c059fd3d8  
 fwd="202.119.45.10" dyno= connect= service=status=503    
 bytes=protocol=https
```

and I also try to load it locally with command

```
heroku local
```

the command window always shows like this:

```
2:52:27 PM web.1 |  [2018-11-16 14:52:27 +0800] [1950] [INFO] Starting
gunicorn 19.9.0

2:52:27 PM web.1 |  [2018-11-16 14:52:27 +0800] [1950] [INFO] Listening     
at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1950)

2:52:27 PM web.1 |  [2018-11-16 14:52:27 +0800] [1950] [INFO] Using worker: sync

2:52:27 PM web.1 |  [2018-11-16 14:52:27 +0800] [1953] [INFO] Booting   
worker with pid: 1953
```

and I need to push "control"+"C" to exit

Help me please

Comment: What do you get on heroku logs? You can check heroku logs by running `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: What is in your Procfile?

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['desolate-oasis-71960.herokuapp.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have solved this by re-building Procfile by using command  in terminator:

```
touch .Procfile
```

and I delete my .git file(have to delete this file), 
then re-initialize .git file by command

```
git init
```

and it worked.